# WordPress adds empty <p> tags after HTML comments

Tags: wordpress

I have found multiple posts on stackoverflow regarding how to fix this but none of them work.  I have the Karma theme and wp-ecommerce.  All the `<!-- html comments !-->` are being wrapped by `<p>` tags by WordPress.

These do not seem to work within my functions.php file.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Disabling_the_filter) the following should work

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

But, as you said it's not working so alternatively you can use [**NoAutoP**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/noautop/) or [**No WPautop**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/no-wpautop/) plugin to remove the `p tags`. Hope these will work for you.

You can read [**this answer**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/remove-filter-the-content-wpautop-is-not-working) too, may be it'll be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried both plugins however the issue still remains.  It might be that the actual theme turns it back on later.  I will have to look some more.